# Does Spark MLlib IDF shuffle data?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

In the following code, does spark have to shuffle data while computing IDF and TF-IDF vectors?

```
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
val tf: RDD[Vector] = hashingTF.transform(documents)
tf.cache()
val idf = new IDF().fit(tf)
val tfidf: RDD[Vector] = idf.transform(tf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't shuffle:

- Both `transform` methods are implemented using `RDD.map`
- `IDF.fit` is implemented using `RDD.treeAggregate`.

The `fit` method can be still quite expensive when `miDocFreq` is low.